# Razor view can't find definition in the tuple object

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, tuples

I want to get value in tuple item1 whit **for loop**

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<dynamic>, IEnumerable<AbbA.Models.Card_Stock>>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Item1.Count(); i++)
{
   @Model.Item1.ElementAt(i).Code
   Or
   @Model.Item1[i].Code
}
```

I take an error, *'object' a 'Code' does not contain a definition* but Item1 have Code definition.

Thanks.

Comment: Why `dynamic` when you know what the type is?

Comment: it's returned linq Select for example
...Select(x,y,z)
So i don't want to create strongly type, because I'll only use once.

Comment: If you are passing something to a view, I strongly recommend creating a proper type.

Comment: Yes I now but each time so boring. There must be an easier way.

Comment: If you think that's boring, I suggest that you're in the wrong business!

Comment: Just remember, if you don't use a proper class (and that includes replacing Tuple here) then you lose a lot more than you gain. Some basics like compile time type checking, there's nothing stopping someone else calling your view with any type they feel like and they will only get an error. :)